# Disabling edit button in "more" view of tab bar controller does not work in iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios4

In my old app I could completely disable rearranging views in tab bar controller by doing:

tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];

But on iOS4, the Edit button is still displayed, although it displays no items. Is not it possible to hide the edit button completely?

Comment: What is the edit button??  Is that a button that you made?  A tab bar item?  UIBarButtonItem??

Comment: in a tabBarController, if you have more than 5 Views, a "more" view will appear which contains the rest of the views. This "more" view has an edit button that allows the user to rearrange views. I did not want this in my app, and I could not disable it in iOS4.0

Comment: hi adranale, i have same problem, if you solve this please tell me. my id is velugoti.nanda@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record:

Under iOS4.1 the edit button does not appear any more when setting the `customizableViewControllers` to empty array.

Looks like Apple solved the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have same problem. I have tried as you specified. But still It is showing the edit button.

Comment: As I mentioned, it was mysteriously resolved! Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: I am using iOS4.2 and I tried by changing the deployment target from 3.0 to 4.2. But no luck with any iOS.

Answer (score 4):

Add below function in app delegate.m file;

```
/*  code to remove edit button in more view */

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UINavigationBar *morenavbar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    UINavigationItem *morenavitem = morenavbar.topItem;

    /* We don't need Edit button in More screen. */
    morenavitem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out the line

```
//  tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
```

it works for me :-)